# All QDL tools won't see hard-bricked moto g8 power when trying blankflash

Tags: adb, unbricking, motorola-moto-g

I am trying to unbrick my hard-bricked Moto G8 Power, but with all the blankflash tools I have used, the only response is:

```
< waiting for device >
```

When running lsusb, the phone shows up as:

```
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 05c6:9008 Qualcomm, Inc. Gobi Wireless Modem (QDL mode)
```

I aspect to need the rawprogram* and patch*.xml files, but I haven't been able to find any.

Any solution?

Comment: *"All QDL tools"* - what tool? what cmd?

Comment: Running LM 21.2 and Debian 10 under ChromeOS (both same result) and these tools: https://mirrors.lolinet.com/firmware/motorola/sofia/blankflash/ and https://github.com/linux-msm/qdl